# Aligning three menu elements to the center of the screen, and a logo staying in the top left isn't working for me

Tags: html, css, flexbox, frontend, tailwind-css

I am using tailwindCSS. What I'd like to do is create the traditional nav we've all seen minus a third element. So the header, or "logo" would stay in the top left. The three menu items should be in the center of the nav.

I have tried many things, and asked chatGPT, and a couple discords. Nobody's solution is working. The text for my links always appears just slightly off from the center, I even measured.

I would like to avoid absolute positioning if possible, as I want it to remain mobile responsive. Adding a third element mostly fixes the problem, however it still appears slightly off kilter.

Grateful for any help.

````
        <h1>Nathaniel Reeves</h1>
        <div class="flex gap-3 mx-auto">
            <a href="#">Services</a>
            <a href="#">My Work</a>
            <a href="#">The Process</a>
        </div>
    </nav>```
````

Comment: you're centering on the remaining space which is the space excluding the logo. You have to move one of those both out of flow to not occupy space within the calculation

Comment: hi @tacoshy thanks for responding. So do you mean that the h1 should be outside of the flex container? I did try that, then they did not align the same way.

Comment: no to be out of flow either by using `float` or `position: absolute`. PS: nav is not an appropriate container. The logo is semantically not a nav element. An appropriate container would be `header`. the anchors should be within a `nav` container.

Comment: Ok I see. I did not want to use position absolute as the instant I resize my screen, my logo flies off the left off the page. Thanks for pointing out the semantics. Just playing with a personal project